# SWIFT3 JSON NSNull Issue

Tags: json, swift3

I have the following swift3 code.  The JSON can return a NSNull value for the $0[2] value.

```
struct Player3 {
    let name : String
    var score : String
    let avatar : String
}

class HistoricLeagueVC: UITableViewController {

    var players = [Player3]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let urlString = "https://str8red.com/jsonoverallleaderboard/1025/"

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("there was an error")
            } else {
                do {
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[String]]

                    self.players = parsedData.map { Player3(name: $0[0], score: $0[1], avatar: $0[2]) }

                    print(self.players.count)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            }.resume()

    }
```

I have tried to convert it to an empty string without success.  I have also tried to set a default string such as `"https://str8red.com/static/no_profile_picture.png"` which ideally is what I would like to do.

The error in the terminal states `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0xed1c78) to 'NSString' (0x57b6b8).`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you cast `as! [[String]]` if you know there are potentially no strings, but NSNulls in there? I presume that is the line where the code crashes

Comment: That is exactly where the code crashes.  Initially all profiles had a picture so none of them were NSNull BUT obviously some people have joined who have not added a profile picture.  So now I do not know how to handle the NSNull.  Thoughts?

Comment: this is wrong way of doing it, first of all if possible you should avoid ! whenever you can, better use guard statements. Then, you should have some kind of json tree, from this one is not possible to tell what is [0], [1], [2] and if it exists

Comment: Do you actually know what "as!" means? It means "try to convert what I've got, and if you can't, then crash". So that's what's happening. You asked for it to crash, and it did.

Answer (score 0):

Do not cast to `[[String]]` then:

```
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [[Any]]

self.players = parsedData.map { Player3(
    name: ($0[0] as? String) ?? "",
    score: ($0[1] as? String) ?? "",
    avatar: $0[2] as? String, // keeping `nil` here
)}
```

You should probably even `as! [[Any]]` do in a safer manner (using `as?`) but the above will work.

Comment: When I copied in your code it enforced a few corrections on the last line to "avatar: ($0[2] as? String)! // keeping `nil` here
                        )}" 

Then after running the code it still errors at the same place with the same error :/

Comment: @AlanTingey If you put `!` you are reverting to the previous behavior. I have assumed that since not all people have avatars then `avatar` should be an optional. If it is not an optional, use `($0[2] as? String) ?? "")`, not `!`.

Comment: I just changed the "," to ?? "" and it works.  Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will crash brutally if anything goes wrong with your input data. Ask your boss if he or she is Ok with that. I wouldn't. Here's how you will crash: If data == nil (but it shouldn't be if error == nil). You catch the problem that data cannot be parsed without crashing. You crash if data doesn't parse to an array, you crash if the elements of the array are not all arrays, you crash if the elements inside the inner arrays are not all Strings, and you crash if any of the inner arrays contain two or fewer strings. I'd say that is pretty unacceptable.

My strategy would be: If the response cannot be parsed or is not an array of arrays, then ignore it, leaving self.players unchanged. If there is an array of arrays, reset self.players, then add a player for each array that contains at least three items, of which the first two must be strings.

```
guard data != nil else { return }
guard let parsed = try? NSJSONSerialization(with: data!) else { return }
guard let arrays = parsed as? [[Any]] else { return }

self.players.removeAll()
for array in arrays {
    guard array.count >= 3,
    let name = array [0] as? String, 
    let score = array [1] as? String else { continue }
    let avatar = array [2] as? String ?? ""
    self.players.append(Player3 (name: name, score: score, avatar: avatar))
}
```

It's a good idea to move something like this into a separate method. Add whatever error handling or logging you feel is appropriate.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  Luckily there is no boss and we are just "throwing" together a little something with the aim to raise a little money for charity.  When I copy your code in I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'parsed'" and the same with arrays.  Perhaps I copied it to the wrong part?

Comment: This is code that I just typed in. If there are any errors, the compiler will tell you and you fix them.

Comment: Understood, on it :)